# Use session in service with Symfony

Tags: php, session, symfony

I want to use my user session in a service with Symfony.

So, i have in my controller :

```
$service = $this->container->get('myservice');
$timeline = $service->getThing();
```

I need, in the function `getThing()`, retrieve my user session.
I don't want to add the session like `getThing($session)`

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Igor says, inject session (and security context) into your controller (as it is a service).

Services.yml

```
services:
    my.controller:
        class: "%mybundle.controller.foo.class%"
        arguments: [@session, @security.context]
```

Controller;

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class Foo
{
    private $sessionManager;

    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(Session $session, $security_context)
    {
         $this->sessionMananger = $session;
         $this->securityContext = $security_context;
    }

    public function someAction()
    {
        $id = $this->getId();
    }

    private function getId()
    {
        return $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject session to your service. Session key in container is `@session` .

Comment: I have already tried that. i add @session in argument, retrieve $session in the construct of my service, but how can i retrieve the user id with $this->session ?

Comment: You shouldn't pull user from session directly. Instead inject `@security.context` and get user from token.